# Why can't my if state recognize the label's text?

Tags: android, if-statement, label

So although I am not new to programming (I have been developing for `iOS` for about 6 months not) I have just started to learn `Android` development and wanted to make the simplest app ever:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buckysButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buckysButton);

    buckysButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {
            TextView buckysText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buckysText);
            if (buckysText.getText().toString() == "Hello") buckysText.setText("World!");
            else if (buckysText.getText().toString() == "World!") buckysText.setText("Hello");
        }
    });
}
```

I get no errors. However, nothing happens when I press the button. Nothing changes, and yes, I am positive that my tables original text is set to 'Hello' because this is what I have my label set to in strings.xml. `<string name="message_text">Hello</string>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER use `==` on a String! ALWAYS use `.equals()` on a String!

See this question for further explanations: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: You're welcome! When able, you can accept the answer so that the question does not remain "unanswered".